# FadeTo Animation in Xamarin Forms MacOS not working

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am creating a custom frame in Xamarin Forms MacOS. The frame itself looks good, but the idea is for it to fade in when it is getting selected. I have created a bindableproperty that works successfully and the `TranslateBox` method runs just fine.

The issue is `await this.FadeTo(1, 1250, Easing.Linear);`. No animation is happening, instead after 1250 seconds it shows up.

```
public class CustomFrame : Frame
{
    public bool IsExpanded
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsExpandedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsExpandedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty IsExpandedProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
        nameof(IsExpanded),
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(CustomFrame),
        false,
        propertyChanged: IsExpandedChanged
    );

    private static void IsExpandedChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldVal, object newVal)
    {
        var getInstance = (CustomFrame)bindable;
        getInstance.TranslateBox();
    }

    public void TranslateBox()
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            if (this.IsExpanded)
            {
                await this.FadeTo(1, 1250, Easing.Linear);
            }
            else
            {
                await this.FadeTo(0, 1250, Easing.Linear);
            }
        });
    }
 }
```

Any clues what is causing this issue? Is it a known bug, and if so are there any workarounds/hacks out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tested in local site, it works well.

Testing with two button clicked event to change the `IsExpanded` property.

**Xaml** code:

```
<local:CustomFrame x:Name="MyFrame" BackgroundColor="#2196F3">
   <Lable Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" FontSize=""36/>
</local:CustomFrame>
<Button Text="Animate" Clicked="Button_Clicked_1"/>
<Button Text="AnimateBack" Clicked="Button_Clicked_2"/>
```

**Xaml.cs** code:

```
void Button_Clicked_1(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MyFrame.IsExpanded = true;
}

void Button_Clicked_2(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    MyFrame.IsExpanded = false;
}
```

Note: The version of Xamarin.Forms is `4.8.0.1451`, if not the latest version you could update it to check.

Comment: @DiddanDo Hi, it also has animation.